# java telnet client duplicate IAC symbol

Tags: java, telnet

I try to send some option to telnet server, so I use below code:

```
    OutputStream outputStream = telnetClient.getOutputStream();
    byte[] option = new byte[3];
    option[0] = (byte) TelnetCommand.IAC;
    option[1] = (byte) TelnetCommand.DO;
    option[2] = (byte) 3;
    outputStream.write(option);
    outputStream.flush();
```

But in wireshark I see 4 bytes instead of 3:

**0xff 0xff 0xfd 0x03**    instead of   **0xff 0xfd 0x03**

As you can see the 0xff byte is duplicated.
I don't know why this is happened. Has anyone any idea?

Comment: might be part of the command, whats the exact class name of that OutputStream? It might be interpreting your commands before sending them

Comment: I have used debugger and found that output stream has TelnetOutputStream   type and it really double IAC symbol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the `sendCommand()` method to send the `TelnetCommand.DO` which prepends the `0xFF`, followed by the option.

The way you are doing it tells the client to send the bytes as ***data***, so the `0xFF` is escaped in the stream by doubling it.

[RFC 854 - Telnet Protocol Specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc854) is worth looking at.